# Intersection of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $p$ a fixed prime. We condiser $$\bigcap_{k\ge 1} (p^k).$$
I know that this intersection is empty for the Foundamental Theorem, but How can I properly formalize the proof?

Thanks

Comment: The intersection isn't empty but is the zero ideal. The integers in the intersection are those integers that are divisible by all powers of $p$. But any nonzero integer has a highest power of $p$ that divides it, as follows from unique prime factorization. So this intersection doesn't contain nonzero elements, and hence is $=(0)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The theorem of unique factorization is it also true for negative integer?

Comment: First of all the intersection is an ideal. If it is not $(0)$, then it contains a *minimal* positive integer. But $p^k\to\infty$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like a proof to consider the unique factorization theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows what I would consider a more-or-less formal proof of the assertion than $\bigcap_{k \ge 1} (p^k) = \{0\}$, where $p \in \Bbb P$ is a prime:

If

$\displaystyle \bigcap_{k\ge 1} (p^k) \ne \{0\}, \tag 1$

then

$\exists 0 \ne z \in \Bbb Z, \; z \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{k \ge 1} (p^k), \tag 2$

and since $\bigcap_{k \ge 1} (p^k)$ is an ideal,

$z \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{k \ge 1} (p^k) \Longleftrightarrow -z \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{k \ge 1} (p^k); \tag 3$

thus we may assume

$z > 0; \tag 4$

now by (2) we have

$\forall k \ge 1, \; z \in (p^k); \tag 5$

then

$\forall k \ge 1 \; \exists 0 < m_k \in \Bbb Z, z = m_k p^k; \tag 6$

we observe that if $z \ne 0$ then this forces $z > 1$; however, then this contradicts the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), which asserts that the prime factorization of every positive integer is unique.  We thus conclude that (1) is false, i.e. that

$\displaystyle \bigcap_{k\ge 1} (p^k) = \{0\}. \tag 7$